# Why my [UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] is crashing?

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, uiscrollview

The crash log is below.

Do you know any particular reason why might `[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview]` can crash? The scrollview contains view hierarchy with different types of `UIViews`. I also finds that the ad hoc version crash often not the debug version. I could not find any reason for that.

Same viewcontroller is loaded in a different flow in iPhone that works fine. But in iPad it crashes. 
In iPad, in a container view controller, only viewcontroler.view is loaded.

```
Incident Identifier: EE102239-34D1-4BE7-8B52-41F74AB26203
CrashReporter Key:   2b11ea2a01ac5618e199ffc5a1e1f321600bb6a9
Hardware Model:      iPad3,4
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-06-18 15:19:16.132 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3bab7070 prepareForMethodLookup + 20
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3bab6fb2 lookUpMethod + 42
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3bab6f7e _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 14
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3bab6638 objc_msgSend_uncached + 24
4   QuartzCore                      0x357f2a72 CA::Layer::contents_visibility_changed(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 50
5   QuartzCore                      0x357f29de CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 190
6   QuartzCore                      0x357f29b2 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 146
7   QuartzCore                      0x357f29b2 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 146
8   QuartzCore                      0x357f29b2 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 146
9   QuartzCore                      0x357f29b2 CA::Layer::mark_visible(CA::Transaction*, bool) + 146
10  QuartzCore                      0x357f28d2 CA::Layer::update_removed_sublayer(CA::Transaction*, unsigned int) + 18
11  QuartzCore                      0x357f255a CA::Layer::remove_sublayer(CA::Transaction*, CALayer*) + 130
12  QuartzCore                      0x357f246a CA::Layer::remove_from_superlayer() + 34
13  UIKit                           0x35a6e92c -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 144
14  UIKit                           0x35b857bc -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 60
15  MyApp           0x000bde8a -[iPadNavigationController vcAnimationDone] (iPadNavigationController.m:400)
16  UIKit                           0x35a55ab6 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 154
17  UIKit                           0x35aca8f8 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 44
18  QuartzCore                      0x35801304 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 204
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x3bed55d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x3bed8e40 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 224
21  CoreFoundation                  0x33c051ac __CFRunLoopRun + 1284
22  CoreFoundation                  0x33b78238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
23  CoreFoundation                  0x33b780c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
24  GraphicsServices                0x37733336 GSEventRunModal + 70
25  UIKit                           0x35a942b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
```

A few line from the code (as asked),

```
    previous = showing;
    showing = [ vc retain ];
    showing.view.frame = startFrameIn;
    [ container addSubview:showing.view ];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [ UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context ];
    [ UIView setAnimationDelegate:self ];
    [ UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(vcAnimationDone) ];
    [ UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut ];
    [ UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4 ];

    previous.view.frame = endFrameOut;
    showing.view.frame = detailFrame;

    [ UIView commitAnimations ];
}

- (void) vcAnimationDone {
    if ( previous != nil ) {
        if (previous.view.superview != nil) {
            [previous.view removeFromSuperview];
        }
        [ previous release ];
        previous = nil;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code, that caused the crash.

Comment: Is it possible another animation is still running? It seems that some message is to be sent to `nil` instance. Is it compiled under ARC?

Comment: try to run it in simulator with instrument looking for zombies

Comment: What version of iOS are you writing for? Manual Reference Counting, animation methods that were deprecated in iOS4…

Comment: for iOS 4.3. For each button button press in iPad, I have 4 vc to load. And the load reload with animation. So its true other animation running when loading another vc. I could not reproduce it in debug mode, only adhoc mode I have this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers, tips and tricks. However one thing I want share with you is the cause of the crash. I found that the crash was at different thread in different times. I had several views loaded with button pressing/menu in my iPad app. Some of the button pressing  fetch data from web service. So I was bit confused to get the cuase of crash, animation, or url connection etc... I tried with enabled NSZombie objects, but it did not show any information.
Then I tried with Guard Malloc. This only runs in Simulator. And magically I found the code point of crash. I have function to convert a hex string into data. There I have line of code to make a C string null terminated. where I assigned 0 at the last index. and that makes the crash!

```
tmpCh[count] = 0;
```

I do not why, but probably it takes some time in the memory management procedure in iOS so it crash at different thread at different times. But with Guard malloc in Simulator, it always point out here and when I rewrite the code, the crash is gone.

```
/* Converts a hex string to bytes.
 Precondition:
 . The hex string can be separated by space or not.
 . the string length without space or 0x, must be even. 2 symbols for one byte/char
 . sample input: 23 3A F1 OR 233AF1
 */
+ (NSData *) dataFromHexString:(NSString*)hexString
{

    if (hexString.length < 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    char * tmpCh = (char *) malloc([hexString length] * sizeof(char));
    int count = 0;
    for (int k=0; k<hexString.length;k++) {
        char c = [hexString characterAtIndex:k];

        if (c == (char)0x20) { //skip space
            continue;
        }

        if (c == '0') { // skip 0x
            if(k+1 < hexString.length){
                if ([hexString characterAtIndex:k+1] == 'x'
                    || [hexString characterAtIndex:k+1] == 'X' )
                {
                    k = k + 1;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        tmpCh[count] = c;
        count++;
    }
    tmpCh[count] = 0; // make null terminated string

    if (count % 2) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:tmpCh];
    free(tmpCh);

    if ([temp length] % 2 != 0) {
        return  nil;
    }

    NSMutableData *result = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    unsigned char byte;
    char hexChars[3] = {0};
    for (int i=0; i < (temp.length/2); i++) {
        hexChars[0] = [temp characterAtIndex:i*2];
        hexChars[1] = [temp characterAtIndex:i*2+1];

        if (![Util isValidChar:hexChars[0]] || ![Util isValidChar:hexChars[1]]) {
            return nil;
        }
        byte = strtol(hexChars, NULL, 16);
        [result appendBytes:&byte length:1];
    }

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithData:result];
    [result release];
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A very probable reason is that you are overreleasing your scrollview or one of the views inside it.

Calling `removeFromSuperview` then deallocates the view instead of simply decreasing the retain count.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you are still stuck with non-ARC project, [Static Code Analysis](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Analyze/Analyze.html) is very useful for this kind of bug. Retain/release balancing issues are hard to pin down, and nearly impossible with incomplete method so I suggest you post the full method body if possible.